# Django Mixin with arguments saying too many values for __init__

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a Mixin similar to:

```
class MixinWithArgs(object):
  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
    self.thing1 = arg1
    self.thing2 = arg2
```

and a template view that I'm attempting like so:

```
class ArgView(MixinWithArgs('one', 'two'), TemplateView):
  template_name = 'template.html'
```

and on page render I get 'init takes 3 values, 4 given'

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning an object in your mixin. When that object is instantiated with the view base classes, it must allow its superclass **init** args,kwargs to pass through your init, which you cannot as you defined your args already. Remember ordering of subclasses is important, the class farthest from the left gets priority.

TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases

This tells you it was impossible to instantiate your view object from your subclasses.